# Parameters undefined using lmfit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, lmfit

I am trying to fit a curve to the equation below with the given data. The equation is `Rate=k*Concentration^n`. I am having trouble as the `n` when fitted is `-6`, which is not possible so I am trying to set a bound at `min=0`. However, I am getting a undefined term parameter errors. Any help would be great thanks.

```
from IPython import get_ipython 
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



# Homework Problem #2 
Time = np.array ([0, 48, 76, 124, 204, 238, 289])
Concentration =np.array ([19.04, 17.6, 16.9, 15.8, 14.41, 13.94, 13.37])

# Rate Determination 
Rate=Concentration/Time 


# Model Definition 

def rateEq(Concentration, k, n):
    return k*(Concentration)**n

# Model creation
model=Model(rateEq)

# Parameters
params = parameters()
params.add(k=0.001)
params.add(n=0.001)
par.set(min=0)


# Data Fit v
result=model.fit(Rate, params, Concentration=Concentration)
# Print and Plot Results 
print(result.fit_report())
result.plot_fit()
```

Comment: I've made some improvements to your question awaiting approval. Post your error code where I made the edit by modifying your question. Welcome to SO, finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`parameters` is undefined because you do not define it anywhere. You use it as  `params = parameters()`, probably implying a function call, but you do not define or import that function....  Similarly, `par` is undefined because you do not define it anywhere.

You almost certainly want

```
from lmfit import Model, Parameters # explicitly import Parameters

params = Parameters() # note the capitalization
params.add('k', value=0.001)
params.add('n', value=0.001)
```

what is less clear (because I cannot guess what `par` is)
is whether you want

```
params['k'].min = 0
```

or

```
params['n'].min = 0
```

Also, just as a warning:  Since your `time[0]` is 0, your `Rate[0]` will be infinite, which will cause trouble when running the fit.